# Vagrant with Ansible Provisioning - How to git clone private repo

Tags: git, ssh, vagrant, ansible

I am using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) to setup a shared development server. I am trying to use [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) for the provisioning (having previously used bash scripts). I can't seem to correctly configure things so Ansible can automatically clone our private gitlab repos during the provisioning stage.

Our Vagrantfile is

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.synced_folder /my/local/dir/, "/home/vagrant/repos"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".",   "/vagrant"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
  end
end
```

Our basic playbook looks like

```
---

- hosts: all
  sudo: true
  tasks:
    - name: update apt cache
      apt: update_cache=yes

    - name: install git
      apt:  name=git state=present

    - name: clone test repo
      shell: ssh-keyscan -H our.private.gitlab.server >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts; ssh -T git@our.private.gitlab.server; git clone git@our.private.gitlab.server:me/amazing-repo.git
```

I have an `ansible.cfg` file with the following

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

I get the following error during the provision stage (despite verifying on the host machine with `ssh-add -L` that the agent has my key)

> Permission denied (publickey).\r\nCloning into
>   'amazing-repo'...\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not
>   read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct
>   access rights\nand the repository exists."

I have read articles such as [this](http://blog.kollerie.com/2014/02/18/ansible_git_ssh/) and [this](https://stefanscherer.github.io/access-private-github-repos-in-vagrant-up/) (and many more besides), but I can't get it working.

I just want the provision step to take care of cloning the repos. I then will have them synced to my local machine, so any commits/pushes will be using my locally stored ssh key.

---

### Update

It seems related to [this issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1735) but I can't see any resolution currently.
@Lukáš Lalinský's suggestion works on OSX but not Windows. On Windows, the git clone step fails during provisioning, but if I then ssh into the machine, the ssh key is forwarded to the VM and the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` exists. I can clone at this stage, just not during provisioning.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you run `sudo`, you lose access to the SSH agent socket. The only way around the problem is changing `/etc/sudoers` on the server to preserve the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable.

For example, add this to `/etc/sudoers` as one of the first tasks in your playbook:

```
Defaults env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
```

Comment: This works perfectly on OSX, but not Windows for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the settings I needed to git clone a private repo within a Vagrant box configured by Ansible, with the following versions:

- Vagrant 2.0.1
- Ansible 2.4.1.0
- Box `ubuntu/xenial64` — Ubuntu 16.04.3
- VirtualBox 5.1.30 which probably shouldn’t matter
- macOS 10.13

In your `Vagrantfile`, configure your Ansible provisioner to use SSH agent forwarding:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  # ...
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  # ...
end
```

Now, add your git server as to your known hosts on guest:

```
# todo: better to add to the file instead of overwrite, but only if not already present
- name: set up bitbucket.org as a known host
  shell: 'ssh-keyscan -H bitbucket.org > /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts'
```

Next, add the task to clone the repo. We need to specify that the task should *not* be run as root, so that SSH agent forwarding will work:

```
- name: clone repo
  become: no # to use ssh agent forwarding, must not be root
  git:
    repo: 'git@bitbucket.org:myuser/myrepo.git'
    dest: /path/to/myrepo
```

In my case, this resulted in a permissions issue because once I wasn't running `git clone` as root, I no longer had permission to create the destination directory. So I added a prior `file` task to create the directory as root with editable permissions.